# How can I implement Listener in a non-widget class

Tags: java, swt, listener

I have a custom class wherein I do not want to use widgets. I want to `implement Listener` but my `handleEvent` override does not receive mouse events.

```
public class HTMLComponent implements Listener {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        switch (e.type)
            case SWT.MouseDown: System.out.println("down"); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added `HTMLComponent` as a SWT.MouseDown listener on some control somewhere?

Comment: (Sorry, can't get a newline, but)  Yes, I generate `HTMLComponents` in another object that `implements Listener`: `HTMLComponent hc = new HTMLComponent();
     addListener(SWT.MouseDown, hc);

     hc.setBounds(rect);
     hc.setHTML(parentObsVals.get(0).toString());'